# using iptables for testing application

Tags: networking, iptables, ip

I'm testing my webapplication which connects to two DBs. I can't stop them but I want to simulate outage of one of them.

So I opened one terminal where I'm pinging DB server:

```
 ping 172.21.7.188
```

In the second terminal I did:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 172.21.7.188 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 172.21.7.188 -j DROP
```

But I don't see any change - pings still return. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you may be using Ubuntu, this question is not Ubuntu-specific, but Linux-specific, so I think it would be better to ask it on ServerFault.

---

**Answer to the original question (before OP edited it)**

Your rule in INPUT chain is correct, but the rule in OUTPUT chain is wrong. You want to drop there packets addressed to the mentioned IP, not the ones coming from it (which is pointless in this chain).

That's why you have to change `-s` (`--source`) to `-d` (`--destination`) in the rule:

```
# iptables -A OUTPUT -d 172.21.7.188 -j DROP
```

But even when you were dropping only incoming packets, it was kind of enough, one could say. It's true that ping was returning (ICMP echo reply was reaching your host) without above line, and consulting tcpdump or wireshark would show ping-related datagrams (i.e. outgoing and incoming), but the `ping` application wasn't receiving incoming datagrams, because they were dropped.

Obviously it's rather unwise to drop only incoming packets in most of the cases, because it leads to different state on both ends of the connection (at connection level or at application level).

---

**Answer to edited question**

If after correction it still doesn't work, then I suspect your firewall has already some rules that make your new rules unreachable. The way you added your rules makes them appended at the end of the chain. You should remove your new rules first (same commands as for appending, but change `-A` to `-D`).

Now add your rules to the beginning of chains (i.e. insert them at given rule number 1) they are suited for (same commands as for appending, change `-A` to `-I`):

```
# iptables -I INPUT  -s 172.21.7.188 -j DROP
# iptables -I OUTPUT -d 172.21.7.188 -j DROP
```

Now it should work.

Comment: Corrected '-s' to '-d'. I can still see pings, though. If this is normal because pings are neither TCP nor UDP than, is there any other way to constantly poll the server and see how it reacts as I update iptables?

Comment: Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
```

This Will Block The Ping

I'm using This Script For Iptables in Our Server's

```
#!/bin/bash 

#This Script was Used for Only Setting up Iptables in ubuntu 12.04 server
#uncomment the Lines With # Which u don't need to use 
#if u going to use this script in remote VPS Test it in local systems before applying it in remote VPS .
#final line will be commented with # cos it will save the iptables if its not commented with #


#0. Flush every Rules what ever there already 

iptables -F

#1. This enable traffic for (lo) loopback interface(-i) 


iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT


#2. This Will Keep the rules for Which service currently Established  eg : ssh


iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT


#3. This Will Enable the Port Number 22 for ssh which i we have defined 


iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT


#4.This Will Enable the Port Number 80 for http 


iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT


#5.This Will Enable the Port Number 443 for httpd 


iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT


#6. Allow rsync from a specific network


iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 873 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 873 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


#7. Blow ICMP PING Request 

iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP


#11. This Will Block Other connections 


iptables -A INPUT -j DROP



#saving the iptables 


#sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
#sudo service iptables-persistent save
#sudo service iptables-persistent restart
```

Comment: But I don't want to block JUST ping. I want to block all connection (IN and OUT from/to all ports) from this machine.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really interested in the script you are using in your company. I'm interested in correct answer to my question. In the comment above I don't see any IP specified so I guess this will block connection from all machines which I don't need.

Comment: iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

This Will Block All incoming and Outgoing Dont try it in remote servers , if so you will loose your Connection and cant access any more if its saved .. if not saved u can restart your Remote server and it will rectify from it ..

Comment: Did u need to block for a particular PC ?

Comment: Yes - this is clearly stated in my question.

Comment: iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.25 -j DROP

Replace the Ipaddress With you need to block and Add another for OUTPUT too 
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.25 -j DROP

Comment: In the comment above - what difference do you see between what you are suggesting and what I wrote in my question? These rules are exactly the same and they are not working for me.

Comment: Have u saved the iptables-save ?